# How to navigate to specific screen in other react fragment during auth flow?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Let's say there is a auth flow as such:

```
state.userToken == null ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />   //User logout action
    <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePasswordScreen} /> //Navigation link to ResetPassword
  </>
);
```

Let's say the during change password in ChangePasswordScreen the user forgets the current password and wants to navigate to the ResetPassword screen which is in other react fragment.

Or let's say upon logout from the ProfileScreen, the user should be navigated to the SignIn screen.

Currently it navigates to the first and foremost screen in the navigation stack that is OnboardingScreen upon logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the example below:

```
{state.needsOnoarding === false ? (
          <>
            {state.userToken == null ? (
              <>
                <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingScreen} />
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />   //User logout action
                <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePasswordScreen} /> //Navigation link to ResetPassword
                <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
              </>
            )}
          </>
        ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingScreen} />
            </>
          )}
```

You need to store (use something like SQLite, realm (Does not support Hermes at the moment), RocksDB or anything else you already use to store info) if a user did the onboarding flow. If that is done, the onboarding flow won't be showed by default but the sign in screen will. Onboarding is still possible if you have a route for that on the sign in screen.

For your reset password, I think you could add twice the same screen in the differents stacks. But you should also think about your design, would it be logic when you already logged in, but you forgot your current password to show the same reset password screen that probably has an other design than when you are logged in.